# ggplot2 - Adding All Data Labels to One Section of Stacked Barchart with Facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that is very imbalanced in terms of how it looks as a stacked bar graph. I need to label my data, and I was thinking of putting the labels of all the stacked data in one of the stacks, so they are legible.

Here is an example that is close to my data:

```
year <- c(2011,2012,2012,2013,2013,2011,2011,2012,2012,2013,2013)
type <- c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B')
ind <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
n <- c(9000,5,9000,5,9000,10,10000,10,10000,10,10000)
pct<-c(1,0.01,0.99,0.01,0.99,0.01,0.99,0.01,0.99,0.01,0.99)

df <- data.frame(year, type, ind, n, pct)
df$ind <- as.factor(df$ind)
rm(year, type, ind, n, pct)
```

I want to create a graph that looks like this:
[image: Correct Graph]

Here is my current ggplot2 code:

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(df,aes(factor(year,levels=c('2013','2012','2011')),pct,fill=ind)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity",position="stack") +
geom_text(aes(label=ifelse(ind=="1",
                  paste0("YES\n",format(n,big.mark=","), " (",sprintf("%.0f", pct*100),"%)"),
                  paste0("NO\n", format(n,big.mark=","), " (",sprintf("%.0f", pct*100),"%)"))
                  ),
           position=position_dodge(width=1)) + 
theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
axis.ticks=element_blank(),
axis.text.x =element_blank(),
panel.grid=element_blank(),
panel.background = element_blank(),
legend.position="none") +
facet_grid(.~factor(type,levels=c('A','B')), scale='free') + 
coord_flip()
```

The code that I have currently outputs the following graph:
[image: Incorrect Graph]

My question is, how do I fix the labels so that they display like the first graph?

Comment: Have you tried `geom_text(aes(label=ind, y=0.5), position=position_dodge(width=1))`?

Comment: @lukeA if I do that, the labels overlap each other in the center

Comment: Hmm my `packageVersion("ggplot2")` is `‘3.0.0’`, and it looks pretty much the way you want it to look. Do you use older package versions? (Dunno if sth changed.)

Comment: mine is also `'3.0.0'`...weird!

Comment: @crayfishcray: restart your R session maybe?

Comment: if I label it with the `ind` variable, it does work. With the ifelse label, I had to add extra lines to make it not overlap. Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add `y = 0.5` like this:

```
year <- c(2011,2012,2012,2013,2013,2011,2011,2012,2012,2013,2013)
type <- c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B')
ind <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
n <- c(9000,5,9000,5,9000,10,10000,10,10000,10,10000)
pct<-c(1,0.01,0.99,0.01,0.99,0.01,0.99,0.01,0.99,0.01,0.99)
df <- data.frame(year, type, ind, n, pct)
df$ind <- as.factor(df$ind)

library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(df,aes(factor(year,levels=c('2013','2012','2011')),pct,fill=ind)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label=ind, y=0.5), position=position_dodge(width=1)) + 
  facet_grid(.~factor(type,levels=c('A','B')), scale='free') + 
  coord_flip()
```

it gives me a plot like this:

[image]